# qt sqlite select statement

Tags: qt, sqlite, select

I decided to test sqlite db for my Qt application.

I have created the sqlite db file with the proper statements (create table etc. and Inserted some rows of data).
My problem is that when I execute a select statement I don't get any records.

This is the code I use:

```
qq.sprintf("SELECT * from descriptors WHERE descriptors.id=%d ",idx);
query.exec(qq);
if( query.isSelect() ){
    while (query.next()){

    int fff = query.value(0).toInt();
```

}}

The problem is that I never get inside the while loop. query.next() doesn't seem to work.

any hints?
thanks in advance,
Thodoris

p.s. I forgot to write my configuration so: Qt 4.7.3, windows 7, visual studio 2008

Comment: You should not construct your queries like that. [Use bindings instead](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), otherwise [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) will strike again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comic.  I used this kind of query construction with mysql and worked fine. I'll try using bindings to see what happens and I will update

Comment: Of course it'll work fine. Until Bobby Tables comes along. Just because it works fine doesn't mean that it's OK. It's like running STOP signs. It works until someone dies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the mistake hexa posted, `query.isSelect()` will always return true even if the query failed. You need to check the result of `exec()`:

```cpp
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare( "SELECT * FROM descriptors WHERE id = ?" );
query.bindValue( 0, idx ); // assuming idx is an integer/long/QVariant value

if( !query.exec() )
{
  // Error Handling, check query.lastError(), probably return
}

// Note: if you don't return in case of an error, put this into the else{} part
while( query.next() )
{
    int fff = query.value( 0 ).toInt();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this didn't work either. I guess that is not something with the syntax but something else... 
I'll keep you all updated with my results.
thanks again

Comment: OK thanks solved. There was a combination of problems. first the bindings and second the database file that was not properly constructed (the int where saved as strings). Thanks again for helping figure this out

Answer (score 0):

In my case, backward iteration over QSqlQueries worked. I think this could be a bug somewhere in the QSQLite Driver implementation.

```
QSqlQuery q = db.exec("SELECT * FROM Table");
if (q.last()) {
    do {
        // Do something with row...
    } while (q.previous());
}
```